# How to get exactly the same JSON format that I need with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need this JSON format:

```
{
 "1" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}],
 "2" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}],
 "3" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}],
 "4" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}],
 "5" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}],
 "6" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}],
 "7" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]
}
```

But with PHP I'm Getting this format:

```
[
 {"1" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"2" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"3" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"4" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"5" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"6" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"7" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
]
```

The Index "1","2".... corresponds to a day of the week. Each Index has 'n' range of hours (arrays) with the format {start: "", end: ""},...

For example:
{start: "12:00:00",end:"14:00:00"},{start: "14:00:00","15:00:00"},...

I'm getting the days from a table using PHP functions, then I iterate with a 'foreach' to get in each iteration the range of hours from the same table, then I iterate those ranges to create the desired format.

The last step is formating using 'json_encode'.

```
    //Getting all days data from DB given user ID 
    $aDays = Schedule::getDays($nIdUser);

    //Array to Store Data
    $aJson = [];

    //Iteration
    foreach ($aDays as  $aInfoDay) {

        //Getting single day hour range given day ID 
        $aRangesHours = Schedule::getDayRanges("id_day = {$aInfoDay['id_day']} AND id_user = {$nIdUser}");
        $aParsedDay = [];

        //Iterate Ranges
        foreach ($aRangesHours as $aRangeHour) {
            $aParsedDay[$aRangeHour['id_day']][] = array('start' => $aRangeHour['startHour'],'end' => $aRangeHour['endHour']);
        }

        //Store Data in aJson Array
        $aJson[] = $aParsedDay;
    }
```

Comment: This is the real code? Because you create `$aParsedDay` as empty array, then append to `$aJson` still empty.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You already have the code to generate the "wrong" output. Just play with it (and maybe read a PHP tutorial about arrays).

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON. What's wrong with the JSON you are actually getting?

Comment: Thanks @FelippeDuarte, I just updated it.

Comment: The problem is that the plugin that I use  to manage the days and the ranges in the front require the format that I mentioned.

Comment: That is correct json and corresponding php array -  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8418d79faf6f7b07b60f4c92e6d38b8937823517

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the edit suggestions. After digging a little in the JSON format, I figure out that I need to create Array Objects instead of Arrays:

```
    //Getting all days data from DB given user ID
    $aDays = Schedule::getDays($nIdUser);

    //Object Array to Store Data
    $oJson = (object)array();

    //Iteration
    foreach ($aDays as  $aInfoDay) {

        //Getting single day hour ranges given day ID
        $aRangesHours = Schedule::getDayRanges("id_day = {$aInfoDay['id_day']} AND id_user = {$nIdUser}");

        //Array to Store all Hour Ranges in a Day
        $aParsedDay = array();

        //Iterate Ranges
        foreach ($aRangesHours as $aRangeHour) {

            //Object Array to Store Single Hour Range
            $oRange = (object)array();
            $oRange->start = $aRangeHour['startHour'];
            $oRange->end = $aRangeHour['endHour'];

            //Pushing Range object to $aParsedDay Array, this is for keeping the [{"start":"","end":""},...}] format 
            array_push($aParsedDay,$oRange);

            //Saving $aParsedDay in $oJson Object, the name of the index will be the current 'id_day'
            $oJson->{$aRangeHour['id_day']} = $aParsedDay;
        }
    }

    //result
    echo json_encode($oJson);
```

Getting the desired format:

```
{
 "1" : [{"start": "12:00:00", "end": "13:00:00"}],
 "2" : [{"start": "09:00:00", "end": "10:00:00"},{"start": "10:00:00", "end": "12:00:00"}],
 "3" : [{"start": "15:00:00", "end": "16:00:00"},{"start": "16:00:00", "end": "17:00:00"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
let arr = [
 {"1" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"2" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"3" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"4" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"5" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"6" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
 {"7" : [{"start": "", "end": ""}]},
];

let obj = {};

arr.map((item,index) => {
 obj[index + 1] = item[index + 1];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do `$aJson[] = $aParseDay;`, you are considering `$aJson` as an array of `$aParseDay` objects. What you need to do is to change your second foreach to assign `start` and `end` to an `id_day` key inside `$aJson`.

```
foreach ($aDays as  $aInfoDay) {
    $aRangesHours = Schedule::getDayRanges("id_day = {$aInfoDay['id_day']} AND id_user = {$nIdUser}");
    $aParsedDay = [];

    foreach ($aRangesHours as $aRangeHour) {
        $aJson[$aRangeHour['id_day']][] = ['start' => $aRangeHour['startHour'],'end' => $aRangeHour['endHour']];
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the output from this?

Comment: An array that when encoded will give him the json structure he wants

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, it was just a typo. He fixed it. What matters is that `json_encode` would give him a valid one

Comment: It is valid now. He changed [ ] to { }

Comment: That was the issue, normally edits like this (changing OPs intention, what they are expecting as output) is frowned upon and should not be done, but in this case I can see OP approved the edit so they must agree this is their actual desired output. In cases like this, it's usually better to try to get clarification from the OP to change their own expected output (I requested clarification as a comment)